# How to reduce number of stalls in 5 stage pipeline

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

How to optimise code by reducing stalls or instruction count?

I'm trying to execute d = (a+b)*(b-c) in MIPS and wondered if my code can be made more efficient.

```
LW $1, 1($0)              #LOAD A 
LW $2, 2($0)              #LOAD B 
LW $3, 3($0)              #LOAD C 
ADD $ZERO, $ZERO, $ZERO   #NOP 
ADD $1, $1, $2            #ADD A & B 
SUB $3, $2, $3            #SUBTRACT B & C 
ADD $ZERO, $ZERO, $ZERO   #NOP 
ADD $ZERO, $ZERO, $ZERO   #NOP 
MUL $3, $1, $3            #MULTIPLY A & C 
ADD $ZERO, $ZERO, $ZERO   #NOP 
ADD $ZERO, $ZERO, $ZERO   #NOP 
SW $3, 4($0)              #STORE D
```

[Image of data and its addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF6OO.png)

Note that this is a word addressable implementation & the default value in $0 can be assumed to be 0.

Comment: `LW $1, 1($0)` - that's obviously wrong, 0 + 1 = 1, which is not a 4-byte aligned address.  (register `$0` always reads as 0).  LW (4-byte load) faults on unaligned addresses.  Not to mention that the loads would overlap if they didn't fault.  Perhaps you meant `lbu` to load a single byte with zero-extension?  Or `lb` with sign-extension since you're using `add` to trap on signed overflow.

Comment: But anyway, most of those NOPs look unnecessary even without reordering; e.g. you don't use the `$3` load result right away. so the ADD of the first 2 load results can go in the load delay slot for the 3rd load.

Comment: That's a lot of nops, is this on an implementation with no forwarding?

Comment: MIPS I (classic MIPS that actually did have a 5-stage pipeline) doesn't have the `mul` instruction, only `mult` which puts the results in `lo` and `hi`.    (https://www.assemblylanguagetuts.com/mips-multiplication-mul-mult-sll/ shows basic usage.  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Arithmetic_Instructions#Multiplication_and_Division).  `mul` was new with MIPS32 in 1999. At least gcc doesn't use it with `-march=` anything older than mip32 (https://godbolt.org/z/2CeMTw), not even high-end out-of-order MIPS CPUs like `-march=r14000` from 2001: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R10000#R14000)

Comment: Having a `mul` instruction with 2 or more cycle latency on a simple 5-stage MIPS wouldn't be very practical: it would create write-back conflicts with otherwise independent instructions when it tries to produce a result in the same cycle as an ADD that started N-1 cycles later.  I guess you could have the ID stage detect this structural hazard and stall, but this is why classic MIPS's `mult` instruction puts the results in special registers that presumably have their own write-back path connected to the multiplier / divider hardware, separate from the main register file.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Hi, I am using the ISE Design Suite 14.4 which is word addressable.

Comment: @harold yes this is on an implementation with no forwarding

Comment: Ok, so this is a variant of the MIPS ISA, and isn't a classic MIPS I.  (Apparently implemented on a (simulated) FPGA?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xilinx_ISE).  Anyway,  you need to edit the question with the (no) forwarding details and the latency for load and multiply; classic MIPS I only has 1 load-delay slot architecturally, and I think didn't need to stall internally so there's no way we can guess the rules for your not-actually-MIPS from your question.

Comment: I don't think there's any room for improvement, though, if all those NOPs are truly needed.  You're already taking advantage of as much ILP as the problem offers (which is not much), unless there is any surrounding code you could interleave.  Or if you don't need to actually store the result back to memory, and can leave it in a register.